# What do the numbers next to user avatars mean?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, user-card

Next to the user's avatar (portrait) and underneath the name, there are 4 numbers. For example:

[image: Example "John Doe" usercard, taken from the Tour.]

I checked the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), but there is no explanation or definition for these numbers given.

I think the first, bold number is "reputation", and that the next one may be the number of badges awarded, but I cannot find any explicit confirmation of this nor can I find any information on what the last two numbers mean.

Am I just missing something in the Tour or in the Help Center? What do these numbers mean, and where is this meaning documented?

Comment: There are three separate badge counts.  Gold, silver, and bronze.

Comment: @David a thats probably what they mean. Four numbers -> [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), gold [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), silver badges, and bronze badges.

Comment: If you hover over it, it generally will tell you want it is

Comment: @Kevin Except on mobile. :-)

Comment: eh, mobile doesn't matter

Comment: This is not only a reasonable [support] question (since there are no duplicates), but it's even a valid (albeit implicit) feature request if not a bug report: what they say about the Tour is true. This information is not there. We all know it, it's obvious to us, but how do we expect a new user to figure this sort of thing out? Downvoting this makes no sense to me. Even if the downvote reason is lack of research effort, the question makes a pretty convincing case for research not solving this problem.

Comment: @CodyGray "hover your mouse over things" is old school web UI design that has stuck around in Stack Overflow. How often do we tell people to hover the mouse over the downvote button for example. I think maybe it's time to admit that it is an obsolete design choice. Kevin B might claim that mobile doesn't matter... yeah it does. Mobiles rule the galaxy now.

Comment: As a frequent mobile user, it can be quite frustrating that a non-small amount of the information on posts is inaccessible.

Comment: @Gimby Hover for more information isn't obsolete design for people that rely on assistive technology on the internet.

Comment: It's mobile that hasn't adapted to the web in this case.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with that, @Gimby. Stack Overflow is and should continue to be designed for maximum information density. Putting a bunch of noise on the page that explains what all the numbers/widgets mean would be irritating and pointless for most of the users of the site, who are regulars and quickly learn what the stuff means after seeing it once. Non-essential stuff like rep and badges should be de-emphasized, quite like they are now (possibly even more so). So I think the design is fine, and doesn't need to be "modernized". However, clear documentation (e.g., the Tour) is essential

Answer (score 13):

In order, from left to right:

- Current site **reputation** a user has (may be abbreviated with `k` or `m` to reduce the number of digits on screen)
- Total number of **gold badges** a user has, which also may be similarly abbreviated, or omitted outright if a user does not have any gold badges.
- Total number of **silver badges** a user has, which may also be similarly abbreviated, or omitted outright if a user does not have any silver badges.
- Total number of **bronze badges** a user has, which may also be similarly abbreviated, or omitted outright if a user does not have any bronze badges.

Comment: It''s not total reputation, it's reputation for the site you are on now. The word total doesn't really fit since it usually refers to the sum of some number of subcategories but that doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @mousetail:  I mean, the ***only*** other time I can think of in which there would be any ambiguity whatsoever about what that total reputation number - on whether or not it's all your rep on one site or all your rep across the network - would be is if you're looking at your [own flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/8440920/mousetail?tab=flair), but sure I'll disambiguate the answer

Comment: Chat, for example, shows your total reputation for every site, even in a chat room for one specific site

Comment: @mousetail: Oh, that's useful to know.  Not a lot of people (like, at all) use chat so that might be another spot where this comes up.  But based on *this* card alone, this looks to be a per-site thing.  Does chat show you the full badge count across the networks too?

Comment: Chat does not, but Area 51 does show your total badge count for every site as one example

Comment: @mousetail:  Doesn't look *that* different from the flair window.  [Here, look at Robert Carantino's display](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31538?phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top) on the old A&M site proposal.  That's [just his flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino?tab=flair).

Comment: In a few places on the site like the commitment page, also actually I checked and it does show total badge count on your chat profile, but not next to your messages

Comment: Stack Exchange chat does that, @mousetail, but Stack Overflow chat doesn't do that because Stack Overflow chat is only associated with one site. Meta Stack Exchange chat doesn't, either, because it's only associated with MSE.